# Qual são as diferenças entre die, exit e __halt_compiler?

Tags: php, sintaxe

Quais são as principiais diferenças entre `die`, `exit` e `__halt_compiler`?

Comment: Pergunta simples e que agrega informação muito útil pra comunidade +1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Sobre `die` e `exit`

Entre `die` e `exit`, não há diferença, eles são os mesmos, segundo o manual. Um é apelido para o outro.

**Manual PHP para [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):**

> Note: This language construct is equivalent to die().

**Manual PHP para [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php):**

> This language construct is equivalent to exit().

## Sobre `__halt_compiler`:

Existe um mecanismo do PHP que permite embutir trechos de dados (inclusive dados binários) que não serão sequer interpretados pelo interpretador de PHP. Diferente do comando `exit`, que interrompe a execução do script, mas não interrompe o parser do PHP, existe o comando `__halt_compiler`, que ignora absolutamente tudo que esteja abaixo do ponto em que foi chamado.

A utilização deste recurso é pouco comum, mas permite, por exemplo:

Criação de scripts PHP auto-extratores (anexa um pacote de dados ao script)
Criação de arquivos que exigem autenticação para acesso, mas ficam em uma área pública na Web
Armazenar meta-informações sobre o script PHP.
O ideal, é que o próprio script consiga "ler" o que vem depois do ponto em que foi chamado o `__halt_compiler`. Para tanto, existe uma constante especial chamada `__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__`, que guarda a posição do primeiro byte que está após a chamada do `__halt_compiler()`.

Veja um exemplo simples:

```
<?php

// Abrir o proprio arquivo para leitura
$f = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');

// Posicionar o cursor na posicao do __halt_compiler() + 1
// (+1 pois existe a quebra de linha)
fseek($f, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__ + 1);

// Ler todo conteudo do cursor ate o final do arquivo e fecha-lo
$conteudo = stream_get_contents($f);
fclose($f);

// Fazer algo com o conteudo
echo $conteudo;
exit(0);


__halt_compiler();
tudo que vem aqui é ignorado!
blá blá blá
```

[Fonte sobre `__halt_compiler()`](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/script-php-com-dados-binarios.html)

Answer (score 12):

As funções `die()` e `exit()` são equivalentes, [segundo a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.die.php), e servem para encerrar a execução do script, exibindo uma mensagem adicional.

Já o `__halt_compiler()` tem um finalidade diferente. Ele é utilizado para encerrar o parse do compilador após determinado ponto do arquivo. Se aplicados para o debug de código, o `__halt_compiler()` irá ignorar erros de sintaxe a partir de determinado trecho do arquivo, o que não acontece com o `die()` e `exit()`.

Considere o seguinte script:

```
<?php

echo 'Estou debugando esse script';

die('bye_bye');

Aqui nessa parte existem erros de sintaxe!
```

Ele irá gerar o seguinte erro:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'nessa' (T_STRING) in C:\www\chiqueirinho\halt.php on line 7
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nessa' (T_STRING) in C:\www\chiqueirinho\halt.php on line 7

Agora, alterando o `die` para `__halt_compiler()`:

```
<?php

echo 'Estou debugando esse script';

__halt_compiler();

Aqui nessa parte existem erros de sintaxe!
```

A saída será a seguinte:

> Estou debugando esse script

O `__halt_compiler()` pode ser utilizado também para criação de templates, separando o código da aplicação do layout graças a constante `__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__` que retorna o ponto exato onde o `__halt_compiler()` se localiza no arquivo.

Temos [aqui um exemplo](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/5286233) dessa técnica usada em templates, porém é mais comum encontrar esse tipo de construção de templates com arquivos separados, como foi aplicado [nesse exemplo](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/commit/ed0bfca64e4edd9188b992550ad30b6e425ab061#diff-43976ba065e7c336f26bf7a1db9ddadbL102).