# É possível usar Heredoc com caracteres especiais em uma array?

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, heredoc

Tenho uma array multidimensional, como mostra o exemplo abaixo, mas gostaria de saber, se posso usar um **[Heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)** nela, seria possível? Eu poderia incluir caracteres especiais não escapados, caso seja possível usar o *Heredoc*?

```
$name_code = array
  (
  array("Nome", "HEREDOC"),
  );
```

Código *Heredoc* que pretendia usar no **[array()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)**.

```
$script = <<<CODE
rand@#¨4key"'?></
CODE;
```

Abaixo está a minha tentativa, que falhou.

```
$name_code = array
  (
  array("Nome", $script = <<<CODE
  rand@#¨4key"'?></
  CODE;),
  );
```

Comment: Você tentou e deu problema?

Comment: Sim `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in`, não sei se fui muito claro, mas gostaria de user diretamente na array, adicionei a pergunta o que tentei fazer. Gostaria de ter tudo apenas na array, e não fora dela, deixando o código o mais _limpo_ possível, facilitando a atualização/manutenção.

Comment: Do jeito que está o código não vai funcionar mesmo.. você deve definir a variável `script` fora do `array`, aqui funciona: https://ideone.com/mKln9g

Comment: @zekk o problema maior tá no CODE;

Comment: @Florida cuidado que nesse seu caso, os espaços em branco tão fazendo parte da string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em princípio, o HEREDOC só termina quando encontrar a sequência de caracteres definida, **no começo da linha e no máximo com ; no final** quando necessário.

Correção do seu caso:

```
$name_code = array
  (
  array("Nome", <<<CODE
  rand@#¨4key"'?></
CODE
    ),
  );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0PYXck)**.

**Nota:** Sua string está com espaços em branco no começo   `rand@#¨4key"'?></`

O maior cuidado é selecionar uma *string* que não se repita.

Se não quer que os caracteres sejam escapados, e não haja substituição de variáveis, o que você procura é o NEWDOC, veja as aspas simples:

```
$script = <<<'CODE'
rand@#¨4key"'?></
CODE;
```

> [Diferença de HEREDOC pra NOWDOC em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14258/70)

Agora, se vai pegar os dados binários de algum lugar pra "montar" o PHP, pode ter outros problemas com caracteres especiais na leitura do arquivo. Aí seria necessário usar HEREDOC e escapar os caracteres.

Veja uma comparação no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/kxghDg)**.

Comment: Particularmente,  acho essa sintaxe bem bagunçadinha. Ela "quebra" a ideia da indentação.

Comment: Pra HTML comprido é uma boa, pq a indentação é separada do PHP

Comment: É uma possível solução, sai meio da minha ideia inicial, mas não existem outras formas de fazer tudo dentro da array? Essa é a grande questão.

Comment: @Florida ja atualizei. Foi erro de digitação do heredoc, expliquei melhor.

Comment: No caso, agora recebo o seguinte erro no `CODE;` `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'`

Comment: Sim, foi um ; a mais no que eu colei, essas coisas tem que ler a mensagem de erro :) - Atualizei e pus uma demonstração

Comment: Ah, sim, agora imprimiu perfeitamente, de fato nunca idia saber que esse `;` não seria necessário aí.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez não seja a solução deseja, mas uma outra alternativa a se analisar seria a utilização de `__halt_compiler` combinado com `file_get_contents`.

Veja:

```
$name_code = array (
  array(
   "Nome", file_get_contents(__FILE__, null, null, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__)),
);

__halt_compiler();

Posso botar qualquer coisa aqui! $#<?php não vai ser processado ?>
```

É possível aprender mais sobre `__halt_compiler` nessa [ótima resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72495/4995) da pelo usuário [@gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4751/gmsantos).

Comment: Se ele não precisar de mais uma string, é uma alternativa boa. Mas lembre que isso obriga o PHP reabrir o arquivo como stream

Comment: Verdade @Bacco.

Comment: Digo, dá na mesma que criar um arquivo separado e abrir. O valor do __halt_compiler é mais uma comodidade pra deixar tudo num lugar só onde facilitar a organização. Mas é bom vc ensinar a galera :)

Comment: Estou a utilizar várias strings, apenas deixei o código mais limpo para facilitar a compreensão.