# como botar o php no html

Tags: php, html5, xampp

esta dando erro no meu código e eu não sei o porque..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo <<<_END
        isso e um teste
        _END;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

esta aparecendo este erro

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\php\apenasteste.php on line 17
```

eu estou usando um servidor apache o AMPPS para escrever as minhas paginas.

Answer (score 5):

Estou partindo do pressuposto que você está justamente aprendendo a usar o HEREDOC (e tem o NOWDOC também).

O fato é que o fim do heredoc não pode ser indentado. o `_END;` tem que estar na margem esquerda.

Do próprio [manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> ***Aviso:** É muito importante notar que a linha que contêm o identificador de fechamento não deve conter nenhum outro caractere, com exceção do ponto-e-vírgula (;). Isso significa que o identificador não deve ser indentado e não deve ter nenhum espaço ou tabulações antes ou depois do ponto-e-vírgula. Também é importante perceber que o primeiro caractere antes do identificador de fechamento deve ser uma nova linha como definido pelo sistema operacional local. Isso é, \n em sistemas UNIX, incluindo o MAC OS X. O identificador de fechamento também deve ser seguido por uma nova linha.*

### Código ajustado:

Além de ajustar o final do `HEREDOC`, tirei os espaços do "abre PHP" e "fecha PHP" para que eles não saiam no HTML final.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        echo <<<_END
        isso e um teste
_END;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

### Saiba mais sobre `HEREDOC` e `NOWDOC` nestes links:

[Para que serve <<< EOH no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/70)

[É possível usar Heredoc com caracteres especiais em uma array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145807/70)

Answer (score 2):

Olá, se deseja somente imprir algo não precisa usar `heredoc`, pode usar convencionalmente as aspas simples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "isso e um teste";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Também pode usar uma forma abreviada usando a tags `<?=` e `?>`.

```
<body>
    <?= "isso e um teste" ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Coisas em aberto na resposta que seria interessante explicar: **1)** Não precisa usar heredoc, mas por que mudar? **2)** Que convenção de aspas simples é essa que citou? **3)** Por que utilizou aspas duplas se citou a convenção de aspas simples?