# Funcionamento da função die()

Tags: php

Utilizando esse trecho de código como exemplo, a função **die()** poderia substituir o return e o exit? A mesma pode ter o mesmo funcionamento do return?

```
public function error()
{
    if(!$this->connection || !$this->statement) {
        return (object) array(
            'exception' => $this->connection->errno,
            'error' => $this->connection->error
        );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `die` e `exit` são sinônimos e ela não pode substituir `return`, caso contrário o PHP encerraria a aplicação ao invés de retornar o valor. Ps.: Caso você queira retornar o valor, o `exit` é desnecessário nesse método; Caso você queira encerrar a aplicação, o `return` tornar-se-ia desnecessário.

Comment: Relacioanda: [Qual é a diferença entre die, exit e __halt_compiler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72473/91)

Comment: A propósito `exit` nunca será executado, pois o `return` já sai da função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, ele não pode substituir o return, o return é a resposta sobre oque ocorreu dentro da função, pois em casa de exceção você deve trata-lo onde chamou a função, um exemplo é quando algo é falso ou verdadeiro, quando você chama uma função e ela não ocorre como o devido, geralmente ela retorna falso, ex:

```
 if(função){
    //Ocorreu com sucesso
 }else{
    //Deu algum erro
    die('Algum erro ocorreu!');
 }
```